# Post request body as XML string in node.js

Tags: node.js, xml, fetch-api

I am trying to post XML string instead of JSON object to `node.js` server using fetch API.

This is my code which post JSON object:

```
handleSubmit = async e => {

    e.preventDefault();
    var request = JSON.stringify({
        drug: this.state.drug,
        disease: this.state.disease,
        type: this.state.type    
    });
    var xmlRequest = js2xmlparser.parse("request", request);

    const response = await fetch('/api/submit', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: request
    });

    const body = await response.text();

    this.setState({
        responseToPost: body
    });
}
```

How to edit the code to post XML string(xmlRequest) instead of JSON (request) in the request body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send `xmlRequest` instead of `request` in the body. Also change the `Content-Type` to `text/xml` or `application/xml`

```
const request = {
    drug: this.state.drug,
    disease: this.state.disease,
    type: this.state.type    
};

const xmlRequest = js2xmlparser.parse('request', request);

const response = await fetch('/api/submit', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'text/xml'
    },
    body: xmlRequest
});
```

`js2xmlparser` takes an object as second argument, don't use `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: I change the code as above exactly . But , after running the server and print the req body in console  ```console.log(req.body)``` it print { } empty request !!

Comment: You asked how to send `xml` to the server, and that's how you do it. Check the network tab and see that you're actually sending the XML.
Why your server is not accepting it or not, is out of the scope of this question and not something we can tell you with the given information. You should post the server code, or better yet create a different question for that, and I'll be happy to help you.

Comment: Why are you sending it in `XML` if your server can't handle it though? if `req.body` is empty, it means you are not parsing XML. You should implement or use an XML body parser...